# How to add attribute to hyperlink only for specific URLs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to add an attribute for specific URL (a knowledge-base) to open it at a new tab.

My code:

```
jQuery("a[href^='http://knowledgebase.sample.net']").attr("target","_blank");
```

That was my script in `functions.php`:

```
function target_blank_script() {
  // register your script location, dependencies and version
  wp_register_script('target_blank', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/target_blank.js',array('jquery'), '1.0' );
  // enqueue the script
  wp_enqueue_script('target_blank');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'target_blank_script');
```

But that is not working.

Comment: which part didn't work? does the html output the `/js/target_blank.js` correctly?

Comment: Your selector looks fine to me, are you hitting it with a breakpoint?

Comment: yes, path is correct. 

acctually, I`m confusing myself. I am trying to do this a right way, as WP wanted, and its a problem. If I add it simply to the footer, it works perfectly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is failing because the link does not exist at the time the jQuery script runs, since it is loaded in the HEAD. You need to ask WP to load the script at the bottom of the page.

```
function target_blank_script() {
    wp_eneueue_script(
        'target_blank',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/target_blank.js',
        array('jquery'),
       '1.0'
        true
    };
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'target_blank_script');
```

The key is the last parameter (true) which tells WP to load it in the footer. Note that you do not need to register a script if you are going to enqueue it right away.